# Redux Store value change is very slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, redux, hashmap

I am faced with a unique situation where a simple object updation in React-Redux store using Thunk is sometimes quick but sometimes really slow.

The method from my actions.js file ->

```
export function updateDataTileHashmap(hashmap) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_DATATILE_HASHMAP,
      payload: {
        dataTileHashmap: hashmap
      }
    });
  };
}
```

The function updating the reducer ->

```
function dashboardReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_DATATILE_HASHMAP: {
      return {
        ...state, dataTileHashmap: {...action.payload.dataTileHashmap}
      };
    }
```

This same method when called with the dataTileHashmap having 67000 keys flat with true and false values takes 0.1 to 5 milliseconds to execute where as sometimes with just 500 keys takes 250-2500 milliseconds to execute.
Has anyone ever faced similar issue and can help me out ?

Comment: How do you benchmark reducers? Try `redux-log-slow-reducers` to actually detect slow reducers. Also it can be slow when react re-renders. Also consider `redux-ignore` to improve performance of your application. https://redux.js.org/faq/performance

Comment: Hi @RafaelHovsepyan, Thanks for your reply.
I am benchmarking in this way:

    const t1 = performance.now();
    dispatch(updateDataTileHashmap(dataTileHashmap));
    const t2 = performance.now();
    console.log("updated hashmap- " + (t2 - t1) + " milliseconds.");

Hence time to re-render should not affect us here.